# Mysql cascade delete with set null doesn't work

Tags: mysql, cascading-deletes

I have table reviews, having foreign keys to other tables with some relation actions (on delete cascade for user_id, on delete set null for mark_id and comment_id).
When comment or mark is deleted corresponding fk in reviews table are set to null, but when user for that row is deleted only mark_id and comment_id set to null, but review row still exists. It looks like delete action was interrupted. During the query no errors displayed.

Reviews table

```
create table reviews
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id int unsigned not null,
    movie_id int unsigned not null,
    mark_id int unsigned null,
    comment_id int unsigned null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    comment_points tinyint(1) not null,
    mark_points tinyint(1) not null,
    constraint recalls_user_id_movie_id_unique
        unique (user_id, movie_id),
    constraint reviews_user_id_foreign
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint reviews_mark_id_foreign
        foreign key (mark_id) references marks (id)
            on delete set null,
    constraint reviews_comment_id_foreign
        foreign key (comment_id) references comments (id)
            on delete set null
)
engine=InnoDB collate=utf8_unicode_ci
;

create index reviews_mark_id_foreign
    on reviews (mark_id)
;

create index reviews_comment_id_foreign
    on reviews (comment_id)
;
```

Sql to delete user

```
-- for example
    DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 5
```

Users Table

```
create table users
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    email varchar(128) null,
    phone varchar(60) null,
    password varchar(60) null,
    fb_id varchar(60) null,
    vk_id varchar(60) null,
    first_name varchar(60) null collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    last_name varchar(60) null collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    birthday date null,
    gender enum('male', 'female') null,
    city_id int null,
    status enum('wanttocinema', 'youpay', 'ipay') default 'wanttocinema' not null,
    latitude double(12,9) null,
    longitude double(12,9) null,
    is_online int unsigned null,
    is_vip int unsigned null,
    points int default '0' not null,
    blocked tinyint default '0' not null,
    unblock_date date null,
    vk_sharing int unsigned null,
    fb_sharing int unsigned null,
    filter_male tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    filter_female tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    secure_location tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    secure_status tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    secure_feed tinyint(1) default '0' not null,
    walk_message_sound tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    walk_message_push tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    walk_message_banner tinyint(1) default '0' not null,
    new_message_sound tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    new_message_push tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    new_message_banner tinyint(1) default '0' not null,
    walk_changes tinyint(1) default '1' not null,
    is_top tinyint(1) default '0' not null,
    public_at int unsigned null,
    deleted_by enum('user', 'admin') null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    deleted_at timestamp null,
    filter_age_min int default '16' not null,
    filter_age_max int default '100' not null,
    constraint users_email_unique
        unique (email),
    constraint users_phone_unique
        unique (phone),
    constraint users_fb_id_unique
        unique (fb_id),
    constraint users_vk_id_unique
        unique (vk_id)
)
engine=InnoDB collate=utf8_unicode_ci
;

create index users_city_id_index
    on users (city_id)
;

create index users_unblock_date_index
    on users (unblock_date)
;

create index users_public_at_index
    on users (public_at)
;
```

Before delete user with id = 5
[image: Before delete user with id = 5]

After delete user with id = 5
[image: After delete user with id = 5]

Comment: Please go all the way to a [mcve]. That includes using text, not images, for text including code & tables. Please explain 'interrupted'.

Comment: Interrupted means, that some part of row was set to null (mark_id and comment_id) after user was deleted, but the review row wasn't deleted.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into posts, not comments. PS You shouldn't expect others to know what you mean by that because it is based on an idiosyncratic notion of implementation not guaranteed by the DBMS. Please give an [mcve] so we know the actual input to, state of & output from the DBMS & database for your query.

Comment: @Cyborg Please add the full error message you get from MySQL when deleting this user to your question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4zTcmPSRRPBhFMea6PS7z5/0).

Comment: I see.. But still no ideas about my problem. There is not fk to reviews table that could be a problem. All of them has cascade delete..

Comment: @Cyborg What is the error message you get when you try to delete the user?